# How to increase the font size of the body text and sections

Tags: fonts, emacs, latex, org-mode, xelatex

I'm using Emacs and its org mode markup language to generate PDFs. It uses LaTeX however I write the markup similar to a markdown document, then the LaTeX export is handled by Emacs relying on a config file.

[image]

I tried increasing the size of the sections by using the `sectsy` package. It works but only for the first level heading, all the other headings stays the same small size. How can I fix that? I want the other headings to increase as well to some extent. Of course, the second level heading has to be a little bit smaller size than the first level heading and so on.

Also I would like to increase the body text as well just a little bit, like 1pt or something like that.
These are the options I fed to Emacs's config file:

```
  (require 'ox-latex)

  (setq org-latex-compiler "xelatex")
  (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
               '("article"
                 "\\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
                  \\usepackage{fontspec}
                  \\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
                  \\usepackage{geometry}
                  \\geometry{a4paper, left=0.67in, right=0.67in,
                             top=0.5in, bottom=0.67in}
                  \\setlength{\\parindent}{0pt}
                  \\setlength{\\parskip}{1em}
                  \\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
                  \\renewcommand{\\baselinestretch}{1.2}"
                 ("\\section{%s}"       . "\\section*{%s}")
                 ("\\subsection{%s}"    . "\\subsection*{%s}")
                 ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
                 ("\\paragraph{%s}"     . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
                 ("\\subparagraph{%s}"  . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

Comment: For the text size, you might want to modify (or add) another section to `org-latex-classes` which mimics `article` except that it uses e.g. `12pt` as a class option.

Comment: shouldn't be the size specified in this line `\\setmainfont{Charis SIL}` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sectsty` package to also change the size of lower level sectioning commands:

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\Huge}
\subsectionfont{\LARGE}
\subsubsectionfont{\Large}
\paragraphfont{\large}
\subparagraphfont{\normalsize}
```

Comment: Thank you. It already looks better. I was wondering if those `\Huge` `\LARGE` and so on values are hard-coded to a particular size or they are relative to the body text. Would it be possible to specify their size manually in units?

Comment: @ZoltanKing The sizes of `\Huge` etc. will depend on the base size you choose. For example you are loading article class with the 11pt option, which means that the sizes will be defined in the `size11.clo` file in your latex installation. Of course it is possible to specify them manually with `\fontsize{...}{...}`, but you need to come up with harmonic ratios between the steps and make sure that these sizes are available in the font you use - better let latex do this for you.

Comment: Thank you. Now it make sense. I will let LaTeX manage their sizes.
I was wondering why is that if I change `documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}` to `documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}` there is no visible difference. I would love to increase the body text just slightly to a value of 12pt.

Comment: @ZoltanKing Can you show the resulting tex file when you try with the 12pt option?